# why server-sent events do not support headers?

Tags: html, http-headers, server-sent-events

I've been banging my head for days now. I can't send any information at handshake to server, because it's only GET and no headers are allowed. 
my question is WHY?

The alternative they propose is query params and cookies but they are bad for 'security reasons'. So then why headers are banned?